# OData - Calling the MapODataRoute at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

When a request like
http://localhost:12000/odata/Teachers
comes in I'm compiling an Assembly in a middleware. That assembly contains only at runtime available entities and controllers.
I'm attaching these controllers with OData enabled with AssemblyPart to my running web api.

That works quite well and within the same call the newly compiled and added controller can be used to serve the teacher odata query.

My only issue is that I can't register the

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata/teacher", "odata/teacher", GetEdmModel());
});
```

at runtime. Does someone know how to register a new EdmModel at runtime?

Comment: `private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Teacher>("Teachers");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}`. Doesn't this work? Can you describe your problem in detail?

Comment: @Yinqiu: Yes the model I can create at runtime but I want to register this new ODataRoute as it is normally done at startup:

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata/teacher", "odata/teacher", GetEdmModel());
});